# Custom Actions Display Form Ribbon not showing in my Site

Tags: sharepoint-designer, ribbon, site, custom-actions

HELP! I created a custom action ribbon , and set the location to Display Form Ribbon. But when i go to display form of my list i cant find any Ribbon there, can anyone please help me? thanks! I think im following the site i visit on how to create a custom list[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the custom action "Navigate to form" is selected as dispForm... as shown in the screenshot below
[image]

and Ribbon Location is set as below
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Already tried this , unfortunately still not working

Comment: Can you please share the properties of your Custom Action